# how can i make condition to change color using v-bind:class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

Hi i wanna make condition that wen item.status is not ACTIVE then the text will be red.
i have this scripts:

```
<vue-tabs class="row" direction="vertical" value="Description" >      
<div class="static" v-bind:class="{ACTIVE:statusIsActiveFunction(item.status), 'text-danger': !statusIsActiveFunction(item.status)}">

        <div v-for="(item, index) in siteObject.line_info" :key="index">
            <v-tab :title="siteObject.line_info[index].lineid">
                <div class="description text-left">
                    <small v-for="(field, key) in item" :key="key">
                        <strong>{{ key }}</strong> {{ field }}<br>
                    </small>
                </div>
            </v-tab>
        </div>   
        </div>     
      </vue-tabs>
```

but am stuck on the data part i think:

```
 data: {
  isActive: true,
  hasError: false
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<vue-tabs class="row" direction="vertical" value="Description" >
     <div  v-for="(item, index) in siteObject.line_info" :key="index">
        <v-tab :title="siteObject.line_info[index].lineid">
            <div class="description text-left" :class="{ 'text-danger': item.status === 'ACTIVE' }">
                <small v-for="(field, key) in item" :key="key">
                    <strong>{{ key }}</strong> {{ field }}<br>
                </small>
                <pre>{{item.status}}</pre>
            </div>

        </v-tab>

    </div>

  </vue-tabs>
```

and style

```
<style scoped>
  .text-danger {
    color: red !important;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `v-bind:class="{ACTIVE:statusIsActiveFunction(item.status)}`

You simply need `v-bind:class="{ 'ACTIVE' : isActive }"`

So if `isActive` is true, then it will add the `ACTIVE` class.

You can even make it even shorter with `:class="{ 'ACTIVE' : isActive }"` The shortcut for v-bind:class is :class.

Comment: hi thank you i made it but nothing change i chage it  <div class="static" v-bind:class="{ACTIVE:statusIsActiveFunction(item.status), 'text-danger': !statusIsActiveFunction(item.status)}"> with this:  <div  v-bind:class="{ 'ACTIVE' : isActive }">

Comment: @Sofiane do you have a class in your style called `ACTIVE` with `color: red;`? also check the source code of your file, maybe it is adding the class but the styling isn't  working. It may be necessary to write `color: red !important;`

Comment: you right i dont have this how can creat this class can you help me please

Comment: It is just like normal css, create a .css file, and link it to your file. Or go to the `header` of your file and add `<style> .ACTIVE { color:red; } </style>`

Comment: ok i made it <style>
 .ACTIVE { color:red; }
</style> nothing change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174166/discussion-between-sofiane-and-otto).